# Set colour of google bar chart via role:style

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

From a dynamically generate data array I am creating a DataTable and want to style it in a google charts as a bar chart.
I am going thru every data entry and creating a label and annotation.

**But how do I give the column a certain colour?**

I figured out that I need to use the role "style" but could not figure out the right syntax for the colour.

```js
var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
        //Formatters
        var intergerFormatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
            groupingSymbol: ",",
            fractionDigits: 0
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
            intergerFormatter.format(dataTable, i);
        }

        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
        var cols = [0];
        for (var i = 1; i < data[0].length; i++) {
            cols.push({
                sourceColumn: i,
                type: "number",
                label: data[0][i]
            });
            cols.push({
                calc: "stringify",
                sourceColumn: i,
                type: "string",
                role: "annotation"
            });
            cols.push({
                //the following options are not working...
                role: "style: green"
                'color: green'
                color: "#109618"
            });
        }
        view.setColumns(cols);
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('PTCoverage'));
        chart.draw(view, options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `calc` function to return the value for the calculated column...

```
cols.push({
    calc: function () {
      return "green";
    },
    role: "style",
    type: "string"
});
```

**UPDATE**

if the bars for every row in a specific column should be the same color,
don't need the `'style'` column
use the `colors` configuration option instead

the `colors` option takes an array of colors,
one for each column / series

one series...

```
colors: ["green"]
```

two series...

```
colors: ["green", "red"]
```

etc...

**EXAMPLE 1**

using `colors` config option to apply colors to columns...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y0', 'y1', 'y2'],
    ['Test 1',  500, 600, 1200],
    ['Test 2',  500, 600, 1200]
  ]);

  var options = {
    colors: ['green', 'red', 'blue']
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**EXAMPLE 2**

use a `'style'` column to change the colors for column / series 1...
(which basically overrides `"green"`)

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y0', {role: 'style', type: 'string'}, 'y1', 'y2'],
    ['Test 1',  500, 'cyan', 600, 1200],
    ['Test 2',  500, 'magenta', 600, 1200]
  ]);

  var options = {
    colors: ['green', 'red', 'blue']
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks that helped, unfortunately it does not change the colours in the legend. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: ok, sorry It is not my intention to have all columns the same color. I now tried to loop throu an array of color codes:  **var colours = ['#3366CC','#DC3912','#FF9900','#DD4477','#994499','#0099C6','#109618']**  and return it in the calc function, that didn't seem to work.

Comment: sorry, can be confusing, don't need `'style'` column, if each column should be a different color, see __EXAMPLE 1__ above -- _just use the config option_ -- the __UPDATE__ mentions you only need a `'style`' column _if each row within a single column should be a different color_, see __EXAMPLE 2__ above, hope this helps...

Comment: The simple answer for me was to just add colors : ['#3366CC','#DC3912','#DD4477','#FF9900','#AAAA11','#66AA00','#109618'] to the options variable as in your example1. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I now managed to implement an array which returns a new color for evry bar, see below.

```js
var colors = ['#66cc33','#3366CC','#DC3912','#FF9900','#DD4477','#994499','#0099C6','#109618'];
//...
cols.push({
    sourceColumn: i,
    calc: function () { 
        ccount++;
        return colors[ccount];
    },
    role: "style",
    type: "string"
});
//...
```

But this only adds the colors to the data in SR2, SR3 and SR4 have the colors as before, see pic (green color in the left chart, pink color in the midle and right for positive tested)
[image]

**I think** it might be because my data looks like this

```js
        var data = [
            ['Release', 'Test Case missing', 'negative tested', 'untested', 'partially tested','tested with restrictions','part tested with restrictions', 'positive tested'],
            ['SR2', MS2PTStatusMask.TCmissing,MS2PTStatusMask.NegTested,MS2PTStatusMask.UnTested,MS2PTStatusMask.RestTested,MS2PTStatusMask.PartTestWithRest,MS2PTStatusMask.PartTested,MS2PTStatusMask.PosTested],
            ['SR3', MS3PTStatusMask.TCmissing,MS3PTStatusMask.NegTested,MS3PTStatusMask.UnTested,MS3PTStatusMask.RestTested,MS3PTStatusMask.PartTestWithRest,MS3PTStatusMask.PartTested,MS3PTStatusMask.PosTested],
            ['SR4', MS4PTStatusMask.TCmissing,MS4PTStatusMask.NegTested,MS4PTStatusMask.UnTested,MS4PTStatusMask.RestTested,MS4PTStatusMask.PartTestWithRest,MS4PTStatusMask.PartTested,MS4PTStatusMask.PosTested],
        ]
```

**How do I add the colors to the other bars?**